# Drawing lines with C++ and SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I want to create a line with SDL, i know there is a code called `SDL_RenderDrawLine`. But my question probably can not be solved with SDL, because the line that i want to create is lets say 1 m length, there i can say that 100 pixels are 1 meter length, but what will happen if after that, i want to create 0.001 m length?

How to tackle this? because SDL only accepts `int` due to the pixels, in other words there is not 0.1 pixels or half pixel.

if that can not be solved using SDL how can i do it?

Comment: "SDL only accepts `int`"  Oh?  Looks like SDL's had floating-point line-drawing functions since [late 2018](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/commit/8340b0f0e2b84957e2eee444ae83b6b506d9b15d#diff-7cf442df3c7652dae041cd61d70fb2cd6f0e1cbcf819f2037ae7ba24046e58a4R875).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have lower than 1 pixel, this is how computers represent points. If you want to make it look smaller you can create a camera, and while getting closer or further away it will impact the size of the shape you are looking to draw.

In your case by being further away from your line it will look smaller, that said, you cannot have smaller than one pixel, its either one pixel or no pixel.